# Bitnami MEAN restful connection timed out

Tags: node.js, angular, express, mean, bitnami

Hi i'm building a MEAN application using AWS's MEAN stack container with bitnami preinstalled. I have apache with angular running on port 80 and Node.js express running on port 4000. All the rest api calls fail returning connection timed out note this was working perfectly on localhost

Comment: this explanation is not enough to figure out your problem :) share some of your configurations files.

Comment: @EricAska thaks for the response, yes i figured..., hours after i've solved the problem, port 4000 was not open on aws..